# Column alias instead of technical names

Tags: sql-server

I am wondering if it is somehow possible to assign aliases/nicknames/common names to columns which have technical names rather than "easy to read"-names.

Say I have a table, where the columnnames are something like "CD12xxx" and I want to translate that into something readable:

```
| CD12001     | CD12002       | CD12003          | CD12004          |
|-------------|---------------|------------------|------------------|
| Customer ID | Customer Name | Customer Address | Customer Country |
```

Can this only be achieved by creating a `view` and "renaming" all columns with something like `[CD12001] AS Customer_ID` - or is there a nice way of doing this?

In Teradata I have seen something similar at some point, just wondering if it is possible in SQL-Server?

I believe it is SQL-Server 2016 my company is running.

Thanks.

Comment: Practically only if you add a layer above that translates the technical names to human readable ones based on some mapping. But I don't think this could/should be done on sql statement level.

Comment: Your option is to go with a view or have a table storing the mapping and then you could execute dynamic SQL to assign the names.

Comment: Where did "technical names" come from in the first place? Is it a data dictionary design, in which case you should have a table with column descriptions somewhere?

Comment: The data comes from a data warehouse which we just source directly into our own database. I know what all the technical names stand for, just wanted to use the “common names” when creating my query - and I don’t want to change the design of the table from the original source. But sounds like I have to go for a view where I translate the names.